# Dark Souls 2 Compatibility Question

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I own a copy of the original release of Dark Souls 2 on Steam, but my friend was wondering of getting the Scholar of the First Sin edition on Steam. If I want to be able to summon him in my game, would it be possible considering we have different versions?

Comment: Why not do the testing instead of asking?

Comment: @UniKitty Maybe the decision of getting the game depends on the answer. If his friend does not want the game unless they play together, it is a perfectly viable question, and not really testable by himself.

Answer (score 5):

**It depends**

If your friend is buying the [DX 11 version](http://store.steampowered.com/app/335300/), you will not be able to summon him, because the DX 11 Version has a different server.

If he is upgrading from Dark Souls 2 (DX 9) to Scholars of the first sin (DX 9) you will be able to summon him because you are on the same server.

Here's a picture that has a full comparison of the different versions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Dark Souls 2" and "Dark Souls 2: Scholar of the First Sin" edition are not compatible with each other, the DX11 version has some items and enemies that the DX9 version does not. As such, co-op does not work between the two versions.

If you're still in doubt about the versions, here are links to the two different versions on the steam store. [Dark Souls II](http://store.steampowered.com/app/236430/) and [Dark Souls II SotFS](http://store.steampowered.com/app/335300/). There is a 40% discount for people that own the DX9 version.